# On the set N of non-negative integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the fill in blanks type question asked in one exam

On the set N of non-negative integers, the binary operation ______ is associative and non-commutative.

i am not getting any standard operator.Is there any such operator exists or question is wrong?

Comment: Are you limited to a certain class of operations? If not, consider the map $(x, y)\mapsto x$ . . .

Comment: Exactly, that's what my previous comment was describing. Now, is that something you're allowed to put as the answer? Or are you required to list one of a prescribed number of operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OP is not limited to using "common" arithmetic operations, then *projection* gives an easy example. Namely, let $$x*y=x.$$ Then this is associative $$(x*y)*z=x*z=x\quad\mbox{ and }\quad x*(y*z)=x*y=x$$ but not commutative $$1*2=1\quad\mbox{ but }\quad 2*1=2.$$

---

If we're restricted to using "common" operations, then it's unclear whether the question can be answered - what exactly is a "common" operation? However if we drop the associativity requirement, then *exponentiation* is a good example: $2^3=8\not=9=3^2$. Of course exponentiation is not associative, though ($(2^2)^3=4^3=64$ but $2^{2^3}=2^8=256$) so (unless the problem's copied incorrectly) this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

None of the standard operators has those properties. However it is not hard to make up an operator with those properties. The simplest possibility is what in the C programming language is known as the comma operator: It just gives the second argument, $(a,b)\mapsto b$. I'll instead write it as $*$ here.

The operator is clearly associative:
$$(a*b)*c = c = a*(b*c)$$

But is is not commutative: For $a\ne b$ we have
$$a*b = b \ne a = b*a$$

Comment: Note to the OP: this is basically the same as my answer. That said, the structures $(\mathbb{N}, $leftprojection) and $(\mathbb{N}, $rightprojection) *aren't* isomorphic! Even though they have the same idea, left and right projections are algebraically different.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: … which wasn't displayed to me before I submitted mine. But I think the fact that is is not just a theoretical idea, but actually implemented *as operator* in a programming language actually adds to the answer.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing - I just wanted to point out to the OP that even though we've given different examples, they're fundamentally the same (although in another sense they're not).